# Mongodb - group by value and get count

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a aggregate query , which returns result like

```
    {
      count:1,
      status: 'FAILED',
      article_id: 1
    },
    {
      count:1,
      status: 'DELIVERED',
      article_id: 1
    }
```

I want to group by on the article_id and get the count based on the status , something like this:

```
   {
      article_id:1,
      FAILED:1,
      DELIVERED:2
   }
```

How can i archive this? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answers may work in principle, however they are limited hard-coded to status `FAILED` and `DELIVERED`.

In case you like to have a generic solution for arbitrary status, you can use this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $set: { data: [{ k: "$status", v: "$count" }] } },
   {
      $replaceRoot: {
         newRoot: {
            $mergeObjects: [
               { $arrayToObject: "$data" }, { article_id: "$article_id" }
            ]
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $group: {
         _id: "$article_id",
         status: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
      }
   },
   { $set: { status: { $mergeObjects: ["$status"] } } },
   { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$status" } },
])
```

[Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FIdZM-ZjcrN)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
 db.getCollection('artwork').aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: '$article_id',
      FAILED: {
        '$sum': {
          "$cond": [{ "$eq": ["$status", "FAILED"] }, 1, 0]
        }
      },
      DELIVERED: {
        '$sum': {
          "$cond": [{ "$eq": ["$status", "DELIVERED"] }, 1, 0]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8fslUhiFg1-)

Comment: I think you must use `{$sum: {... "$count",0}}` instead of `{$sum: {... 1,0}}`

Answer (score -1):

```
 {
   $group:{
     _id:"$_id",
     articleId:{$addToset:"$article_id"},
     failed:{$addToset:"$failed"},
     delivered:{$addToset:"$delivered"}

   }
 },
 { $addFields:{ 
    article_id:{$size:articleId},
    fail:{$size:"$faild"},
    deliver:{$size:"$faild"},
   }
```

In group $addToSet will return array and in addField will return total length of array. you cans earch $size in mongo
     }